# empty struct as receiver in method

Tags: go

what is the benefit of using empty struct Asn1 here?
Moreover, we are using receiver "a" in Encode() and Decode() methods, but never used in those.
So what is the use here?

```
type Asn1 struct {} // empty struct

func (a *Asn1) Encode(message RmrPayload) ([]byte, error) {
        buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
        asn1 := gob.NewEncoder(buffer)
        if err := asn1.Encode(message); err != nil {
                return nil, err
  }
        return buffer.Bytes(), nil 
}

func (a *Asn1) Decode(data []byte) (RmrPayload, error) {
  message := new(RmrPayload)
  buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
        asn1 := gob.NewDecoder(buffer)
        if err := asn1.Decode(message); err != nil {
                return RmrPayload{}, err 
  }
        return *message, nil 
}
```

making it receiver makes complicated calling Encode() and Decode() method like below

```
  asn1 := new(Asn1)
  message, err := asn1.Decode(payload)
```

why we can not define these two methods without empty struct and call simply as

```
message, err := Decode(payload)
```

Comment: To satisfy an interface, most likely. One could have multiple algorithms for implementing a solution, so compartmentalizing each solution into a unique type is a clean way to easily switch between versions. The alternative - using static functions with unique names - is harder to maintain.

Comment: But here no interface is defined. it should be type Asn1 interface {} in that case.

Comment: In your code there is 0 reason to use a method.

Comment: Interfaces in `go` are not like say `java` where the *implementation* must reference the interface by name. Go's interfaces allow for future planning - where today's implementation may be included in a _future_ interface.

Comment: @colm.anseo, I still could not understand this. Do you want to say that    type Asn1 struct {}         can be changed to   type Asn1 interface {}   in future due to that this is written like this?

Comment: @myquest4sh maybe this example might make it clearer - where two implementations achieve the same results - the interface abstracts ways the details: https://go.dev/play/p/b0PEb7oDOa3

Answer (score 3):

The main reason to define methods on an empty struct is to satisfy an interface.  Bare functions cannot be used this way.

Comment: But here no interface is defined. it should be                     type Asn1 interface {}   in that case.

Comment: No, it would be an interface that Asn1 satisfies. You cannot create methods on interface types, so making Asn1 an interface wouldn't make any sense. But I don't know if an interface makes sense in this specific code. Where did you find this code?

Comment: Interfaces are implemented in the implicit way. Your type implement some interface, if all methods from the interface are defined for the type. There is no clear `implements` directive known from other languages